# Clarification of single responsibility principle

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a clarification regarding Single Responsibility principle in C#.

Suppose I have a method and in the catch block, if I log the error in database, is that a violation of SRP because the method is doing two things at a time?

```
public void Single()
{
    try
    {
        //
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // log into db
    }
}
```

Comment: no it is not a violation.  you are handing the error recording off to a logger and it's the loggers responsibility to record the message/error where it's been configured to do so.

Comment: i'm assuming here you have some sort of ILog or ILogger type to use in your class of course!

Comment: nice ref on the subject here:  http://pragmaticcraftsman.com/2006/07/single-responsibility-principle

Comment: if that was a violation of the SRP, then 99.999% of all code written would be a violation. Also this is a terrible question for stackoverflow, please consider SoftwareEngineering for Pattern questions

Comment: although you delegate responsibility of logging to other entity and inject this logging service to wherever entities that needs this service. you are totally preserving single responsibility by just injecting logging service as a dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have a method called "HandleError" that receives an error and creates a logfile if it doesn't exist. Once it is created, it stores some needed information about the error in this log file.

For me,  if you create this method in a **separate** class, responsible for handling the error logs and call it from your catch, you won't violate the SRP.

But if you create this method in the same class, you probably will be violating the pattern **because your class will have more than one reason to change.**